# In flutter, json decoding of List<String> doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I have this class:

```
class ErrorMessage {
  int          statusCode;
  List<String> message;
  String       error;
  ErrorMessage(this.statusCode, this.message, this.error);

  factory ErrorMessage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ErrorMessage(
    json['statusCode'],
    json['message'],
    json['error']
  );
}
```

And when I call `fromJson` with this data:

```
res.body : {"statusCode":400,"message":["Please enter a name."],"error":"Bad Request"}
```

I got this error: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`

It seems that `message` is not converted to `List<String>`. How can I do so?

Comment: `List<String>.from(json['message'])` or `json['message'].cast<String>()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use type casting to convert `List<dynamic>` to `List<String>` in a loop like this:

```
class ErrorMessage {
  /// {@macro error_message}
  const ErrorMessage({ 
    required this.statusCode,
    required this.message,
    required this.error,
  });

    /// Creates a ErrorMessage from Json map
  factory ErrorMessage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>ErrorMessage(
      statusCode: json['statusCode'] as int,
      message:
          (json['message'] as List<dynamic>).map((e) => e as String).toList(),
      error: json['error'] as String,
    );

  final int statusCode;
  final List<String> message;
  final String error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `map` the `List` of `String` individually,like:

Change

```
 factory ErrorMessage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ErrorMessage(
    json['statusCode'],
    json['message'],
    json['error']
  );
```

to

```
 factory ErrorMessage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>ErrorMessage(
      statusCode: json['statusCode'] as int,
      message:(json['message']).map((e) => e as String).toList(), // Emphasis on this
      error: json['error'] as String,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Model

```
class Response {
  Response({
      this.statusCode,
      this.message,
      this.error,
  });

  int? statusCode;
  List<String>? message;
  String? error;

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
      statusCode: json["statusCode"],
      message: json["message"] == null ? [] : List<String>.from(json["message"]!.map((x) => x)),
      error: json["error"],
  );
  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, and thank you for your answer! Though I chose another solution, this also helps me a lot. I really appreciate it.